# GeoObject из geojson

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я совсем не могу понять что и почему происходит.
Используя статический конструктор карт выделил интересующую меня область на карте и сохранил данные в формате geojson
При последующих импортах отображает все правильно.
Но как только я создаю геообъект используя https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/#GeoObject__methods-summary
И передавая в конструктор данные из полученного ранее geojson карта рисует область совсем не там где она должа находиться....
Хорошо, перевернул координаты (поменял местами широту и долготу) в поле geometry.coordinates область стала рисоваться правильно... но как-то это все вызывает сомнения и недоумения...
Объясните мне что происходит и самое главное почему???

Comment: Сомнения вызывает необходимость менять местами широту и долготу?

Comment: @Quazimorda  ну да...

Comment: Вот здесь вроде про указание порядка latlong или наоборот - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/load-docpage/#load__param

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что координаты объектов заданы в последовательности "долгота, широта". Поскольку по умолчанию в JS API принят порядок "широта, долгота", необходимо при подключении API передать параметр coordorder со значением longlat.

Это указано в [документации API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/)

Comment: А как же быть тогда с обычными объектами типа "point".... им придется тогда переворачивать)))